# SoapServerException.HandleException()

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, exception

I'm confused about how this method is actually handling the exception that is passed to it, it doesn't appear to do anything extra.

I have it in a segment of my code as it was the standard being used in one of the examples I looked at the other day but I've since found that it seems to eat my Exception messages so I am left with the generic `SoapServerException` with no InnerException.

```
// "Exception of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.SoapServer.SoapServerException' was thrown."
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw SoapServerException.HandleException(exception);
}

// "Server was unable to process request. ---> Error in MyService.asmx ---> 
// Could not load file or assembly 'That.Assembly.I.Forgot' or one of its dependencies."
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw new Exception("Error in MyService.asmx", ex);
}
```

Is there a reason I should throw `SoapServerException.HandleException()` instead of my own more descriptive exception?

Answer (score 1):

Per: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg552614(v=office.14).aspx#bestpractice_infodisc

SoapServerException.HandleException() is intended to reduce the details returned to the user for security reasons. So this behavior is intentional.

The documentation for this method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.soapserver.soapserverexception.handleexception.aspx

doesn't really explain what this method does as at all, which is unfortunate. If you deliberately want to provide more details to the user, then you should use your own exception. But be careful about providing such details. It may not be a good idea for security reasons. It really depends on how much you trust/know the party you are sending the error to.

-Dave